# How can I add a theme in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, file-upload, upload, themes

I have a theme and I would like to upload it to VSCode editor

But I don't know how to do it. I searched on YouTube and couldn't find it, I searched on Google.

And the results were strange, so how is this done?

Here is a picture of the theme folder:

[image]

Comment: have you read the VSC extension/theme development docs, just copy this folder to the VSC extension folder

Comment: Hello
I've done this
But I did not find it in the program, and instead, it asked me to install: Install .VSIX
But I didn't know what to do next?

Comment: does the theme work in development? If so you don't get VSIX questions. Don't pack the theme to VSIX, JUST COPY folder

Comment: First, don't be angry
Second, I moved the folder to a folder
C:\Users\TOSHIBA\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\extensions
And I couldn't get to the layout from the program when I hit ctrl + shift + p

Comment: do you want upload my theme in mediafire ?

Comment: copy the folder to the USER VSC extension folder, it looks like you copy it to the program extension folder, or package it in a VSIX file and use the GUI to install see top menu of Extension Bar

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you, thank you, so like you said, I should send it to C:\Users\TOSHIBA\.vscode\extensions and not like I did before, thank you very much, now how do I choose the best answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy the folder with the Theme (containing `package.json`) to the USER VSC extension folder

```
C:\Users\username\.vscode\extensions
```

Or package it in a VSIX file and use the VSC GUI to install. Use the **Extension Bar** top menu (`...`) entry **Install from VSIX...**